# woocommerce reports filter completed orders only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

as we all know from here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/reports/ that woocommerce counts in the sales by date & sales by product By default, orders marked Processing, On Hold and Completed are counted as sales.

What if we want to make it count the orders counted as completed status only ?

N.B: we need this to work in the sales by product and sales by date tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_data_args` filter to change the query. The following code should only show reports for completed orders for the 'sales by date' and 'sales by product' reports:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_data_args', 'only_show_report_for_completed_orders');
function only_show_report_for_completed_orders( $args ) {

    // When accessing the default sales by date report
    if ( !isset( $_GET['tab'] ) || ( !isset( $_GET['report'] ) && isset( $_GET['tab'] ) && $_GET['tab'] == 'orders' ) ) {
        $args['order_status'] = array( 'completed' );

    // When accessing the specific reports
    } elseif ( isset( $_GET['report'] ) && in_array( $_GET['report'], array( 'sales_by_date', 'sales_by_product' ) ) ) {
        $args['order_status'] = array( 'completed' );
    }

    return $args;
}
```

This code snippet should be added to the functions.php of your child theme or via a plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: it worked great but with one issue, yes in the list of top products now it counts as 2 which is the truth we have 2 completed orders and 1 on-hold order: https://snipboard.io/7kqsM5.jpg , but when we select that product specifically it still shows 3 ( it includes the 1 on-hold order )  https://snipboard.io/5H27UJ.jpg we need this because not all products listed in that top products list

Comment: Worked great .. can we have a separate code too to work for the sales by date too ?

Comment: You can use `$_GET` and check for `sales_by_date`.

Comment: Thank you so much but we are not great in php .. can you atleast make it work for both by sales & by product in 1 code ?

Comment: See edited answer. But please be aware that Stack Overflow is not a 'can you please code this for me' site.

Comment: sorry but the code works only with the sales by products, but did not work with the sales by date when the default url is the default visiting reports url: wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-reports (which is the default reports link in woocommerce ) .. it need to click again on the sales by dates to get that url to work: wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-reports&tab=orders&report=sales_by_date

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't take in to account that the sales by date report is the default report that is openend when visiting the reports page or when clicking on the orders tab. See edited answer.

Comment: @what if we just keep the filter line & the funciton line and inside the function without the if & else if, we have inside the funciton         $args['order_status'] = array( 'completed' );
then we return the $args .. this will work too but not just for sales by date & sales for product .. it will work for all the reports pages .. includes the sales by category right ? .. if thats right is it ok to use like that ? .. does this makes any issue ?

Comment: Correct. That will change the order status argument to only include completed orders, for every report that uses this filter.

Comment: So this won't cause any performance issue to the reports page right ?, and the only thing will be changed that it will list only completed orders in the reports pages no matter which page without making other problems right ?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there is now a setting in WooCommerce Reports to do this:

- Go in your backend to **Statistics -> Settings**
- Exclude all status you don't want in your reports except "completed"